# Rounded corners with Customscrolview and SliverList / SliverAppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on an app in Flutter and want to have the following design of my SliverAppBar with the rounded corners to the bottom in my App. How can I do this when I use slivers?

[Design rounded corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWVJn.png)

I found the design on [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/6428387-Messenger-Mobile-Concept) from a [YouTuber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-igXZCCrrc&t=867s&ab_channel=MarcusNg) who created the app as a tutorial but without using a PageView with Slivers

This is a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: PageView(
          children: [
            CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  expandedHeight: 250.0,
                ),
                SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('something'),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  childCount: 10,
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I'd like to help but you're not exactly asking a question in your post. That would make it easier for others to help out! Update the post maybe I can hopefully help out.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question and hope everything is clear now!

Comment: I checked out the YouTube tutorial you provided. It seems the key part is that the `Column` he is using to build the body/scrollable-area can take a `boxDecoration` parameter. This isn't quite an option in the Sliver widget tree, nor is injecting a border to achieve it. As far as I know it's not possible in your case with Sliver Widgets since the `SliverList` object doesn't have the `boxDecoration` parameter. Posibly someone has a clever was to implement this, but I'm not going to say "it's not possible" either since you can maybe use widgets other than the Sliver widgets.

Comment: I really appreciate you tried to help me! I think as well it isn't possible except if their is an option to convert my ```SliverList``` to a container.

Answer (score 1):

use **SliverPadding** like this:

```
   DefaultTabController(
    child:NestedScrollView(
    headerSliverBuilder:
       (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
   return [
        SliverPadding(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
            sliver: new SliverList(
            delegate: new SliverChildListDelegate(
            [YOR_WIDGET()]),
            ),
        );
    ]
```

Comment: That isn't what I wanted to do, but I appreciate you tried to help me!